# How do I find same numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with this program, in Python 3.8.0. I have two text files (they can't be merged). They contain about 1000 numbers, each 15 digits long (look like this `104988537042058`). I have to find the same numbers. Could someone help me? I'm a bit lost. I wrote this program, but I have probably a mistake somewhere. I'm new to programming and I can't find where is the problem.

```
A=open("A.txt",mode="r")
B=open("B.txt",mode="r")
out=open("Spol.txt", mode="w+")
#print(A)
#print(B)
X=""
for lineA in A:
    for lineB in B:
        if lineA==lineB:
            X+=(lineA)
        else:
            ()
        break

A.close()
B.close()
out.write(X)
out.close()
```

Comment: The `break` will break out of the inner loop on its first iteration. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Why append the numbers into 1 large string rather than accumulate them into a list? Also, if all you want to do is to find the numbers in common -- research [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)  in Python. It is possible to do this efficiently in a single line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code, the `break` will exit the loop after the first comparison with lineB. The other issue is when you read a file you use a cursor that is set at the beginning of the file, once you have read through the file the cursor is at the end, so it will be empty every time you try to use the same handle again without resetting the cursor.
Since it seems that you don't care about duplicates I wrote the following code which should accomplish what you want:

```
with open("A.txt") as Af, open("B.txt") as Bf:
    numsA = {int(lineA.strip()) for lineA in Af}
    numsB = {int(lineB.strip()) for lineB in Bf}
    print(numsA & numsB)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not need `else`. Move break inside the condition so it only breaks the inner loop if you find a match:

```
file_A=open("A.txt",mode="r")
file_B=open("B.txt",mode="r")
out=open("Spol.txt", mode="w+")

for lineA in A:
    for lineB in B:
        if lineA==lineB:
            X+=(lineA)
            break

A.close()
B.close()
out.write(X)
out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each line in each file is a number you could use python [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to load all lines from first file to one set and all lines from second file to another set and then use sets intersection. Example:

```py
# Reads into a set the content of file1 line by line
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as fs:
    file1_set = set(fs.readlines())

# Reads into a set the content of file2 line by line
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as fs:
    file2_set = set(fs.readlines())

# After both files contents (the numbers) are in sets
# then uses set intersection to find numbers appearing in both files
print(file1_set.intersection(file2_set))
```

Last line will print all numbers appearing in both files

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop that iterates over B doesn't work, or more precisely, works only once, for first line of A. After that, it is already at the end of B. Ah, yes, and `break` too - will exit after first iteration of the inner loop. You probably meant to put it inside `if`

You can reopen B before the inner loop. In any case, this is extremely slow - although still ok for 1000 numbers. It would be better to read A's content into set and then go once over B, looking for numbers present in the set.

Or, if you are in unix-like environment, just do `cat A.txt B.txt| sort | uniq -d` presuming you don't have repetitions within A or B. If you, you can still do it in shell
`(sort A.txt| uniq; sort B.txt | uniq) | sort | uniq -d`